# Toggle menu error

Tags: jquery, reference, navigation, toggle, nav

I am getting this error when the site goes to mobile and I try and open up the nav menu

ReferenceError: e is not defined
e.preventDefault();

Here is the Jquery I am using

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-toggle').click(function () {
      $('#menu').toggleClass('open');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Is your #menu-toggle a form submit button? if not, I think you dont need to add e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `document.ready(function())` pass `e` into the function like this `$(document).ready(function(e))`. This should solve the problem.